# Monit to monitor 2 searchd instances on one server

Tags: thinking-sphinx, monit

I have 2 rails apps hosted on the same server and each one of them have its own configuration for thinking_sphinx /searchd with different ports configured. I managed to get this set up working and I have 2 instances of searchd running.

My problem is getting Monit to monitor these 2 instances. Even though these 2 instances of searchd have its own PID in separate directories, I was not able to define the configuration in the monitrc because the process names in this case are the same, namely searchd.

In my monitrc, i have 2 separate commands as follows:

```
check process searchd with pidfile /var/www/app1/shared/pids/production.sphinx.pid
start program=....
stop program=....
check process searchd with pidfile /var/www/app2/shared/pids/production.sphinx.pid
start program=...
stop program=...
```

Monit requires a unique process name. Is it possible to start up my second instance of searchd using a different process name?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the process whatever you wish in monit configuration files - it doesn't need to match the executable. So:

```
check process searchd_app1 with pidfile /var/www/app1/shared/pids/production.sphinx.pid
  start program=....
  stop program=....
check process searchd_app2 with pidfile /var/www/app2/shared/pids/production.sphinx.pid
  start program=...
  stop program=...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have actually tried that before posting the question. I did not see the second process being monitored in Monit status. Then I realized I have overlooked restarting Monit daemon but only reloading the upstart configuration thinking that also restart Monit. Anyway after restart, it works. I had it set up correctly all this time and yet not knowing it. Duh. Thanks for the help.